# How to create UIButton and its @selector in a NSObject

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, nsobject

I'm trying to generate a class that can create a UIButton and take care of what happens when you press the button in any view where the button is located. Here is what I'm doing:

*Header File:*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreateButton : NSObject

- (UIButton *)createButton;

@end
```

*Implementation:*

```
#import "CreateButton.h"

@implementation CreateButton

- (UIButton *)createButton
{
    // Instanciate the class
    CreateButton *classInstance = [[CreateButton alloc] init];

    UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    [testButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [testButton addTarget:classInstance action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return testButton;
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked");
}

@end
```

And finally, in the a view controller, I initialize the class and get the button:

```
CreateButton *create = [[CreateButton alloc] init];
UIButton *testButton = [create createButton];
[self.view addSubview:testButton];
```

Now everything is ok up to this point and I can see the button, however, nothing happens when I click it. Surprisingly, if I move the `buttonClicked:` method to my view controller it works just fine. I need to keep all the button wiring inside the NSObject. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem, interesting.

Implementation file will be modified as:

```
- (UIButton *)createButton
{
    UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    [testButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return testButton;
}
```

Then, in the view controller, `CreateButton` class must be pre-defined in the header file `@interface` section. Then in the implementation:

```
create = [[CreateButton alloc] init];
```

and it works! That would be great if you kindly explains this to me.

Comment: you dont need to create a new instance of createButton. you can just use self since its pointing to the same target. classInstance = self

Comment: You're absolutely right! I edited the answer and thanks for the comment. Do you by any chance know why the object must the pre-defined and then initialized?

Comment: you predefine it there since you want everyone that imports your class to be able to access that method. initialization will depend on the programmer its either instance method or a class method (i.e. `-(UIButton *)createButton` or `+(UIButton *)createButton`